# convert csv to json using nested json for each unique column

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a csv file like this:

```
a   b   c   d   e   f
1   3   6   11  16  21
1   4   7   12  16  21
2   3   8   13  18  23
2   4   9   14  18  23
2   5   10  15  18  23
```

I want to get generate json from this csv, and the json will look like

```
{
 {"a":1,
 "data":[{"b":3,"c":6,"d":11},{"b":4,"c":7,"d":12}],
 "e":16,
 "f":21},
{"a":2,
 "data":[{"b":3,"c":8,"d":13},{"b":4,"c":9,"d":14}, 
 {"b":5,"c":10,"d":15}],
 "e":18,
 "f":23}
}
```

here e and f is fixed for each a, only b,c,d is changing. How to do this using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) for nested dictionaries and then convert to json by [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

```
j = (df.groupby(['a','e','f'])['b','c','d']
       .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r'))
       .reset_index(name='data')
       .to_json(orient='records')
       )
```

---

```
print (j)

[{
    "a": 1,
    "e": 16,
    "f": 21,
    "data": [{
        "b": 3,
        "c": 6,
        "d": 11
    }, {
        "b": 4,
        "c": 7,
        "d": 12
    }]
}, {
    "a": 2,
    "e": 18,
    "f": 23,
    "data": [{
        "b": 3,
        "c": 8,
        "d": 13
    }, {
        "b": 4,
        "c": 9,
        "d": 14
    }, {
        "b": 5,
        "c": 10,
        "d": 15
    }]
}]
```

Comment: If want to change the name of the variable b,c and d in the json file, for example the name of the variables in the data frame is b,c,d and i want to change them to b1,c1,d1 in the json file. how to do that ?

Comment: @user10573224 - I think simplist is rename like `j = (df.rename(columns={'b':'b1','c':'c1','d':'d1'})
        .groupby(['a','e','f'])['b1','c1','d1']
       .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r'))
       .reset_index(name='data')
       .to_json(orient='records')
       )`

Comment: @jezreal- what if want to rename a,e,f also to a1,e1,f1 same way i did for b,c and d ??

Comment: @user10573224 - Use same way like above, `j = (df.rename(columns={'b':'b1','c':'c1','d':'d1', 'a':'a1','e':'e1','f':'f1'}) .groupby(['a1','e1','f1'])['b1','c1','d1'] .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r')) .reset_index(name='data') .to_json(orient='records') )`